# Problems while monitoring Application Logs Errors using AWS CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have utilized the facility of Cloud Watch custom metrics to monitor the application logs of my virtual machines. I have successfully done that and created alarms in such a way that, if the SUM of errors is more than 5 in the past 5 minutes, I would be sent a notification to my email. I have been receiving emails accordingly since then.

But today, AWS has sent me three SNS Notifications, **each** stating that 6 errors have occurred. But, when I login to my Cloud Watch Logs, I could see only 6 errors during that time. So, according to alarm, if the errors are more than 5 over the past 5 minutes, it has to send only 1 alarm, but it sent me three.

I am including the snapshots below. Please look into these.

**My alarm :**

[image]

I have been sent the following **mails** by AWS:

1. ) At Tuesday,21 March, **22:17:27 UTC**

[image]

2. ) At Tuesday,21 March, **22:21:27 UTC**

[image]

3. ) At Tuesday,21 March, **22:26:27 UTC**

[image]

But in my **Cloud Watch Logs**, I can find only 6 errors during that period :

[image]

As you can clearly see in the above image, there was no application error after 22:15:37 UTC.

I have been scratching my head to find out the reason behind getting three notifications in this case.

Could anyone tell me the reason behind this?

Comment: Under `Actions`, configure two more notifications -- one for OK and one for INSUFFICIENT DATA.  Have it notify you for all three so you can see all state changes.  That should help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanxx for the reply Michael. But, may I please know how I could troubleshoot doing that?

Comment: It will explain more of the reasoning behind the alarms.  You only know when the set, but not when they clear, and so you don't yet know all of what CloudWatch is using to make its conclusions.  Monitoring all three states should make this more apparent.

Comment: Ok Michael. This kind of behaviour is very rare. I have done what you told me to. Temporarily, Can I change the statistic in alarm to Average instead of Sum. I mean to modify the alarm to send me a notification if the errors average is more than 5 for the last 5 minutes. Would this help? Thanks in advance.